# REST service with java version 7

Tags: java, rest, web, java-7

Can i develop a REST project using java jdk version 7 ? If so where can I get examples?
I have developed a project with jdk version 8 and jax-rs 2.0 , I want my project to be developed with java 7.

Comment: .... you can use the same material you followed, just don't use any Java 8 specific code. Why would you want to go back to a previous version of Java?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it. Eg you could take an older version (<=2.25) of jersey to develop it 
[jersey documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#d0e560)